# Subscriptions not updating when amendment opportunity is closed won

Tags: cpq

We are using Salesforce CPQ. We have created an amendment opportunity with some changes in original quote lines. However, on closed won this opportunity, order is generated but subscription on original contract are not updated. This is happening randomly.

Comment: Did you generate the contract from the Amended Opportunity? Because the changes in the Amended Quote will be reflected only under the Subscriptions Related List of the Contract record after genereting Contract from Amended Opportunity.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/contract-amendments-with-salesforce-cpq/change-an-existing-contract

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the "Contracted" checkbox on the Opportunity/Order ? Updates only write back to the Master contract through the Amendment Opportunity once they are contracted